# AWK count how many instance after pattern match

Tags: awk

For example:

- RXOTG-1388 holds 3 object RM4FD1,RM4FD2,RM4FD3
- RXOTG-1398 holds 3 object VT08D1 VT08D2,VT08D3
- and so on.

Based on this text file I would like to count, using **awk**, how many object each RXOTG holds.

```
RXOTG-1388       RM4FD1               0
                 RM4FD2               0
                 RM4FD3               0

END
RXOTG-1398       VT08D1               0
                 VT08D2               0
                 VT08D3               0

END
RXOTG-1400       VT08S1               0
                 VT08S2               0
                 VT08S3               0

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    /^RXOTG/{
        if(count)
            print count
        printf "%s\t", $1
        count = 0
    }
    /.{6,}/{
        count++
    }
    END{
        print count
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^RXOTG/{x=$1; y=0}/^RXOTG/,/^$/{y++}/^END/{print x": "y-1}' in
```

- `/^RXOTG/{x=$1; y=0}`: if the current record starts with `RXOTG`, assigns the value of the first field to `x` and `0` to `y`;
- `/^RXOTG/,/^$/{y++}`: if the current record is in a range between a record starting with `RXOTG` and an empty record, increases `y`;
- `/^END/{print x": "y-1}`: if the current record starts with `END`, prints the value of `x` followed by `:` followed by the value of `y` decreased by `1`.

```
% cat in
RXOTG-1388       RM4FD1               0
                 RM4FD2               0
                 RM4FD3               0

END
RXOTG-1398       VT08D1               0
                 VT08D2               0
                 VT08D3               0

END
RXOTG-1400       VT08S1               0
                 VT08S2               0
                 VT08S3               0

END
% awk '/^RXOTG/{x=$1; y=0}/^RXOTG/,/^$/{y++}/^END/{print x": "y-1}' in
RXOTG-1388: 3
RXOTG-1398: 3
RXOTG-1400: 3
```